# React native paper text input black bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I'm currently developing a cross platform React Native application. (Non-expo)

I'm using the following:

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.13",
"@react-navigation/core": "^6.1.0",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.4",
"@react-navigation/routers": "^6.1.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
"@testing-library/react-native": "^8.0.0",
"axios": "^0.23.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.1",
"react-native-dotenv": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.1.10",
"react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-localize": "^2.1.5",
"react-native-nfc-manager": "^3.11.0",
"react-native-paper": "^4.10.1",
"react-native-paper-dropdown": "^1.0.7",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-screens": "^3.8.0",
"react-native-select-dropdown": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-skeleton-content": "^1.0.23",
"react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
"react-native-video": "^5.2.0-alpha1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.5",
"reconnect.js": "^1.1.3",
"redux": "^4.1.1",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
},
```

When I create a multiline text input from react native paper I get the following:
[image: Black bar in TextInput by react-native-paper]

Is there something I can do? This is my code:

```
 <TextInput
            testID={'contactMessage'}
            label={'Message'}
            placeholderTextColor={colors.placeholder}
            style={[styles.input, { maxHeight: height * 0.25 }]}
            multiline={true}
            numberOfLines={5}
            maxLength={maxLength}
            value={message}
            onChange={e => {
              setMessage(e.nativeEvent.text)
              setMessageCount(e.nativeEvent.text.length)
            }}
>
```

And in my StyleSheet:

```
input: {
  backgroundColor: colors.surface,
  color: colors.accent,
  marginTop: actuatedNormalize(16),
  width: '100%',
},
```

Comment: have you tried to remove the label?

Comment: @keikai yes I have used placeholder instead. I actually had placeholder in the first placed but changed it to label to see if it would change and it did not. Edit: the only way to get rid of the black bar is changing multiline to false..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
  View,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

const App = props => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TextInput
          testID={'contactMessage'}
          placeholder="Hello hi"
          placeholderTextColor="white"
          style={[styles.input, {height: height * 0.25}]}
          multiline={true}
          numberOfLines={5}
          selectionColor="white"
          activeOutlineColor="red"
          mode="outlined"
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  input: {
    margin: 12,
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});
export default App;
```

Just try this example.
By default TextInput uses mode as 'flat'. So when you look into source code

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/main/src/components/TextInput/TextInputFlat.tsx#L334

```
{!isAndroid && multiline && (
        // Workaround for: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/2799
        // Patch for a multiline TextInput with fixed height, which allow to avoid covering input label with its value.
        <View
          testID="patch-container"
          pointerEvents="none"
          style={[
            StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
            dense ? styles.densePatchContainer : styles.patchContainer,
            {
              backgroundColor: containerStyle.backgroundColor,
              left: paddingLeft,
              right: paddingRight,
            },
          ]}
        />
      )}
```

they added some default height.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still not sure why it happened to be black then? But adding `mode="outlined"` fixed it for me :)